# how to bypass this Access Denied page during web scraping using puppeteer library in javaScript

Tags: web-scraping, deployment, data-science

[screenshot of access denied page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9HWH.png)

I am new to web scraping so I don't know much.
anyone plz help me>
help me with the code part so that I can bypass this access-denied page
Looking for assistance with web scraping. Need help bypassing an "access denied" page. New to web scraping, so any code guidance would be appreciated. Seeking guidance in web scraping as a beginner. Need assistance bypassing an "access denied" page. Appreciate code support to overcome this issue.

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  defaultViewport: false,
  userDataDir: "/tmp"
});
const page = await browser.newPage();

await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 5000));
await browser.close();
```